# How do I know this is not a virus?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

So I want to install XMrig on the RPI, I happen to find the following article

```
https://dev.to/ijason/cpu-mining-on-a-raspberry-pi-1e1d
```

I wanted to know if anything in there is not written, I do have a pool ID and everything I just don't know if any packages contain any damaging effects to my RPI. (Reason, why I am mining, is for experimental purposes I know I won't gain much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit files to Virustotal:

[Virustotal website](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload)

The website search the cybersecurity community uploads and check if any of the binaries or URLs were already reported as malicious.

Also, you can use ShiftLeftScan for Python code, Github code, etc:

```
wget https://github.com/ShiftLeftSecurity/sast-scan/releases/download/v1.9.27/scan

chmod +x scan

sh <(curl https://slscan.sh)

sudo apt install docker.io
sudo systemctl enable --now docker
sudo usermod -aG docker USER

sudo docker run --rm -e "WORKSPACE=${PWD}" -v "$PWD:/app" shiftleft/sast-scan scan
```

https://github.com/ShiftLeftSecurity/sast-scan

Comment: I know that but how do you do it to an rpi. The miner is not the problem it's the packages like the first steps when it says 
`sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake libuv1-dev libssl-dev libhwloc-dev` and `sudo apt-get install -y raspbian-nspawn-64` that I don't know if its a virus or not! (And I cant check via VirusTotal)

Comment: The website itself does not contain virus activity so I thought it was good but I just want to make extra sure that the packages above are not a virus